# Exposing JVM (Kotlin) classes defined with a JSR223 ScriptEngine

Tags: java, kotlin, scripting, jsr223

I'm trying to access a class defined in a script, evaluated with [`ScriptEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).

Consider the following snippet:

```kotlin
package com.example

interface Foo
{
    fun bar()
}

val script = """
import com.example.Foo

class MyFoo : Foo
{
    override fun bar() = println("Hello from MyFoo::bar")
}
"""

fun main()
{
    val scriptEngineManager = ScriptEngineManager()
    val scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("kotlin")
    scriptEngine.eval(script)
}
```

This runs successfully, and now I'd like to instantiate `MyFoo` in the host code.

The only way I've managed to do so successfully is by using [`ScriptEngine::eval`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String)) to return a reference to the class, by evaluating an expression referencing it:

```kotlin
fun main()
{
    val scriptEngineManager = ScriptEngineManager()
    val scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("kotlin")
    scriptEngine.eval(script)
    
    // -- See below --
    val fooKClass = scriptEngine.eval("MyFoo::class") as KClass<Foo>
    val foo = fooKClass.createInstance()
    foo.bar()
}
```

This too, runs successfullly, writing `Hello from MyFoo::bar` to standard out.

However, is there no way to add the script-defined class `MyFoo` to the host JVM classdefs?

```kotlin
fun main()
{
    val scriptEngineManager = ScriptEngineManager()
    val scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("kotlin")
    scriptEngine.eval(script)
    
    // -- See below --
    val fooKClass = Class.forName("MyFoo").kotlin as KClass<Foo>
    val foo = fooKClass.createInstance()
    foo.bar()
}
```

The above predictably fails with a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyFoo`.

Is dynamically evaluating and returning (*from the [`ScriptEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)*) the [`Class<*>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) or [`KClass<*>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/) instance the only way to access it from the host JVM?